# How to auto increment by id range?

Tags: mysql, auto-increment

I'm looking to create a script to add values to a column in my table.
It would be a script that I would execute only once and not a setting of the database or a key.

Currently I have ~ 900 lines so a script would help me!

## Actually

I'm using DBeaver 3.1.0 actually.

`SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "%version%";` return :

```
Variable_name          |Value                       
-----------------------|----------------------------
innodb_version         |1.1.8                       
protocol_version       |10                          
slave_type_conversions |                            
version                |5.5.28-log                  
version_comment        |MySQL Community Server (GPL)
version_compile_machine|x86                         
version_compile_os     |Win64
```

Actually my table look like this :

```
+----------------------------+
|  id  |  id_sort  |  id_tab |
+----------------------------+
|   1  |     0     |    1    |
+----------------------------+
|   2  |     0     |    1    |
+----------------------------+
|   3  |     0     |    2    |
+----------------------------+
|   4  |     0     |    2    |
+----------------------------+
|   5  |     0     |    2    |
+----------------------------+
|   6  |     0     |    3    |
+----------------------------+
|   7  |     0     |    4    |
+----------------------------+
|   8  |     0     |    4    |
+----------------------------+
|   9  |     0     |    5    |
+----------------------------+
|  10  |     0     |    5    |
+----------------------------+
|  11  |     0     |    5    |
+----------------------------+
|  12  |     0     |    6    |
+----------------------------+
```

I tested this to find how to do my update but I can not add it to a `partition by` :

```sql
select t.id, (@rownum := @rownum + 1) as rank
FROM mytable t, 
(SELECT @rownum := 0) r
```

### I need

The idea would be to create values like this (in `id_sort`):

```
+----------------------------+
|  id  |  id_sort  |  id_tab |
+----------------------------+
|   1  |     1     |    1    |
+----------------------------+
|   2  |     2     |    1    |
+----------------------------+
|   3  |     1     |    2    |
+----------------------------+
|   4  |     2     |    2    |
+----------------------------+
|   5  |     3     |    2    |
+----------------------------+
|   6  |     1     |    3    |
+----------------------------+
|   7  |     1     |    4    |
+----------------------------+
|   8  |     2     |    4    |
+----------------------------+
|   9  |     1     |    5    |
+----------------------------+
|  10  |     2     |    5    |
+----------------------------+
|  11  |     3     |    5    |
+----------------------------+
|  12  |     1     |    6    |
+----------------------------+
```

We would have an increment in `id_sort` by `id_tab` range.

Comment: What's the logic behind that numberings? What does "auto increment by id range" mean?

Comment: This is pretty unclear to me. Would you rephrase it ?

Comment: It's for a setting in my application.
The idea would be to add on the existing lines (in a column that I just added, here id_sort) a numbering which is incremented but which returns to 1 with each new id_tab.
The table example above is not clear enough?

Comment: @Hadock it isn't clear. You show what you expect, but don't show what you actually have

Comment: @Cid It's better ?

Comment: @Hadock yes it is

Answer (score 0):

- In a [Derived table](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/derived-tables.html), determine the new `id_sort` value using the Row_number() functionality.
- Join this subquery to the original table on the primary key, and update the `id_sort` field with the new values.

Try the following:

```
UPDATE 
mytable AS t1 
JOIN 
(SELECT id, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id_tab ORDER BY id) as id_sort_new
FROM mytable) AS dt ON dt.id = t1.id 
SET t1.id_sort = dt.id_sort_new
```

Comment: ``ROW_NUMBER()`` does not exist in mysql i have update my question.

Comment: @Hadock It exists in MySQL 8.1 and above. Anyways, your original question contained Row_number(), that is why gave that answer. Nevertheless, I have given you the basic gist about how to approach this problem. You can do the same using Session variables now.

Answer (score 0):

Try this Below

```
UPDATE `mytable` as t1
Left Join
(SELECT *,(@Count:= if(@TempID = `id_tab`, @Count1 +1, 1)) id_sort2,
(@TempID:=`id_tab`) Tempid
FROM (Select @Count:=0,@TempID:=0) sqlvar, `mytable` f
ORDER BY `id_tab`) AS t2 
ON t1.id= t2.id
SET t1.id_sort = t2.id_sort2;
```

Let's Break it Down

```
SELECT *,(@Count:= if(@TempID = `id_tab`, @Count1 +1, 1)) id_sort2,
(@TempID:=`id_tab`) Tempid
FROM (Select @Count:=0,@TempID:=0) sqlvar, `mytable` f
ORDER BY `id_tab`
```

This query above sort the entire Table according to `id_tab` and generates a column `id_sort2` that does a count based on id_tab using variables and if conditions.

Next, I `LEFT JOIN` `mytable as t1` with the above the query above as `t2` with the Key `id`. and `SET t1.id_sort = t2.id_sort2`.

Not sure if it is the best method, but I tested it out and it works.